# Python selenium facebook checkpoint

Tags: python, selenium, facebook

I use Linux to code and run selenium to login my facebook account but it always checkpoint. When i run on Windows, everything go normal, no checkpoint. I tried on 2 account and both were checkpointed even though it connected at the same ip, same user agent. I tried undetected chrome on linux but it didn't work.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them and does what they can to stop you.

Comment: but on windows, it work normal

Comment: Until they detect you. Which might be an hour from now or tomorrow or sometime in the future.

Comment: they detect me by ip or selenium or something?

Comment: Usually details on what is allowed/expected are in the robots txt of a website: https://facebook.com/robots.txt

Comment: @Hixs Yes they use ip and selenium and other things.

Comment: can i use cookies instead?

Comment: Instead of what. And as I said Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So if you find a way around that Facebook will later figure it out and block you.